# Continuing using process from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, process

i have a winform application and a console application... im running the console as a child and the winform as a parent ..anw i want to keep using the same process in another class but thats giving me an error of type : StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet.
here is the following code:
 in the first class :

```
public class form1
{
//in some method:




      Process p = new Process();
                    p.StartInfo.FileName="AIComputer.exe";
                    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
                    p.Start();
                    game.processID = p.Id;


}
```

and in the other class

```
public class Game
{
```

in the form2 load event

```
{
  p = new Process();


            Process[] allprocesses = Process.GetProcesses();
            int i = 0;
            do
            {
                i++;
            } while (allprocesses[i].Id != processID&&i<allprocesses.Count());

            p = allprocesses[i];
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.Start();
}
}
```

i checked my code with breakpoints ..the process p is alright and is catching the specified process from all the processes,,,but something is going wrong...any help plz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't start a process that's already been started and you can't redirect the I/O streams after it's already been started.

Why not just pass the original `Process` object reference from your `form1` instance to the `form2` instance? E.g.:

```
partial class form2
{
    private Process _process;

    public form2(Process process)
    {
        _process = process;
    }
}
```

Then when `form1` creates the `form2` instance (or whatever code does…unfortunately, your code example is not complete enough to know exactly the best route for the reference to take), it can just pass the reference to the `form2` constructor.